# How to access files from module using maven without searching it in local .m2 repository & central maven repository?

Tags: maven

I have two projects. Project A & B. Project B is dependent on project A.
To run project B, I have to add project A's depedency in project B's pom.xml.

If I change something from Project A. I have to do mvn install again to update local repository with latest code of project A. Then I can run Project B.

Can I access Project A's changed code in project B without doing mvn install?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't access the updated code. That is because, when you build a maven application, it will get all the dependencies from your .m2 repository. If it does not find the dependency there, then it will search your remote repository.
In your case, when you update A's code and don't build it, then the updated artifact will not be be available in your .m2 repository. Now if you build Project B, then it will try to fetch project A artiufact from .m2 repository. Since you did not build A after modifying the code, B will fetch the artifact that is currently there in the .m2 folder i.e. the artifact with the old code.
Another approach that you can use is to have a parent pom.  This is just an aggregator pom which will execute the pom.xml for both of your modules. For eg:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multispring</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>module-A</module>
        <module>module-B</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Please be aware that the packaging for this should be **pom**.